# table * has no column named user_id,django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have a app in which i have a  foodpost model which has a foreign key for user. now when i m trying to save instance of foodpost model i m getting "table Food_foodpost has no column named user_id"

i tried deleting migrations,makemigrations and migrate

here is my foodpost model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class FoodPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    details = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Food/',blank = True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    # slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    created_post = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='FoodPost')
    # likes, no. of views

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def delete(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.image.delete()
        super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

serializer

```
class FoodPost_seriallizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FoodPost
        fields =['title',
                   'details',
                    'image',
                    'quantity',
                    'category',
                    'location',
                    'price',
                    'created_post',
                    'status',
                    ]


    def create(self,validated_data):
        # print()
        # print(validated_data)

        foodPost = FoodPost(**validated_data,user=self.context.get("user"))
        foodPost.save()
        # foodPost.save()
        return foodPost
```

and the view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
# @parser_classes([JSONParser,FormParser,MultiPartParser])
def create_post(request):

    serializer = FoodPost_seriallizer(data = request.data,context = {"user":request.user})
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        foodpost = serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and of course the error

```
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table Food_foodpost has no column named user_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/j0/projects/django/Fooda-Gram/foodagram/Food/views.py", line 30, in create_post
    foodpost = serializer.save()
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/j0/projects/django/Fooda-Gram/foodagram/Food/serializers.py", line 27, in create
    foodPost.save()
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 784, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 926, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1384, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/j0/anaconda3/envs/foodagram/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table Food_foodpost has no column named user_id
[30/Jul/2020 07:48:27] "POST /food/create_post/ HTTP/1.1" 500 19896
```

thanks

Comment: If you're using sqlite3, remember to delete the database itself as well before re-migrating (as you didn't mention this in your question)

Comment: @crimsonpython24 ohh sorry i forget it. worked. thanks i wasted like 4hrs on that